# $A \cap B \subset (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C')$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do i show this?

$A \cap B \subset (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C')$ 
$$ x \in A \cap B$$
$$ \implies x \in A \cap B \cup \emptyset$$
$$ \implies x \in A \cap B \cup (C \cap C')$$
$$ \implies x \in (A \cap B \cup C)\cap(A \cap B  \cup C')$$

How do i proceed?

Comment: What about replacing $C$ with $B$ in the third line of your solution?

Comment: $x \in A \cap B \cup (C \cap C') \implies x \in A \cap C \cup (B \cap C')  $??

Comment: is that justified?

Comment: I meant $x \in A \cap B \cup \emptyset \Rightarrow x \in A \cap B \cup (B \cap C')$.

Comment: If i wanted to show $A \cap B \subset (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C')$ how would i then proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that 
$$X \subseteq (X \cap C) \cup (X \cap C')$$

Then
$$A \cap B \subseteq (A \cap B \cap C) \cup (A \cap B \cap C')\subseteq (A  \cap C) \cup ( B \cap C')$$

Comment: $x \in X \implies x \in X \cup \emptyset \implies x \in X \cup ( C \cap C') \implies x \in (X \cup C) \cap (X \cup C')$

Comment: I get the intersections and unions the otherway around :S

Comment: @HMPARTICLE If $x \in X$ then $x \in C$ or $x \in C'$. In the first case $x \in X \cap C$, in the second $x \in X \cap C'$... This inclusion can be proven to be equality.

Comment: @HMPARTICLE If you want to use only sets $$X= X \cap (C \cup C')=(X \cap C) \cup (X \cap C')$$

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE: This answers the previous version of this question.**

I would use a different approach.

**Lemma:** $P\subseteq P\cup Q$

**Proof:**

$$\begin{align}
x\in P & \implies x\in P \lor x\in Q \\
 & \implies x\in P\cup Q
\end{align}$$

**Proof of main problem:**

In the lemma, substitute $P=A\cap B$, $Q=B\cap C'$. Then we get

$$A\cap B\subseteq (A\cap B) \cup (B\cap C')$$

---

If you really want to continue the approach you started (which actually uses my lemma without being explicit),

$$\begin{align}
x\in A\cap B
 &\implies x\in A\cap B \lor x\in B\cap C' \\
 &\implies x\in (A\cap B) \cup (B\cap C')
\end{align}$$

Comment: You have made it as clear as can be. Thanks Rory :)

Comment: Hi, Rory, i made a mistake in typing out my question. I thought it was too good to be true. Sorry.

Comment: I am REALLY sorry. I am such a tool.

Comment: @HMPARTICLE: I would answer the new version of your question in a way very similar to that of N.S. My answer is too close to his to write as a separate answer, so just accept his answer. --Don't feel too bad about your mistake. We all make them!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $x$ is in both $A$ and $B$, i.e. $x \in A \cap B$. Then either $x$ is in $C$, in which case it is then in the intersection $A \cap C$; or it's not in $C$, in which case it is in $C'$, thus it is in $B \cap C'$. In the end, $x$ is in both cases in the union $(A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C')$. Since this was true for all $x \in A \cap B$, it follows that $A \cap B \subset (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C')$.

(This answer is here because I don't believe math should be about wildly manipulating strings of symbols using arcane rules in hopes of getting the correct sequence of symbols at the end of the implication arrow.)

Comment: This answer is great. I feel the same, but lack confidence in what I propose most(all) of the time. +1